# Converting fftw_plan_many_dft_r2c to MATLAB fft

Tags: c, matlab, fortran, fftw

I am trying to convert a Fortran code to MATLAB code. In the Fortran code, they used fftw for fft.I am not sure how perform fftw_plan_many_dft_r2c to MATLAB's fft or fftn funtion. It the Fortran code is:

```
fftw_plan_many_dft_r2c(rank,LzLyLx,howmany,didiR,d_embed,stride,dist,didiK,z_embed,stride,dist,FFTW_MEASURE)
```

How I can perform same fft in MATLAB?

I have tried perform just MATLAB fft,fft2,fftn. But the output was very different.

Comment: Did you read how real to complex transforms work in FFTW? You should: https://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Multi_002dDimensional-DFTs-of-Real-Data.html Also note that FFTW does not do any normalization.

Comment: Otherwise, showing your attempts might help. Note that the original example  is very incomplete, we can only guess what all those symbols appearing in the call are.

Comment: FFTW's `r2c` transform produces only half the complex plane (the redundant part is omitted). MATLAB doesn't have an equivalent function, it always produces the full transform. You'd have to discard half the output of `fft` to produce a similar result. I would instead modify the remainder of the code to use the full complex transform, which will make things simpler and clearer.

Comment: @Solidform  How is this related to the C language?

Comment: @Whozcry about the same way as to Fortran, just remove word `call`. Seriously, even in Fortran the call is made directly to the C API, no intermediate wrapper is present, and we have no information how all those symbols are declared and defined anyway.

Comment: Trsnslation frome one language to another language rarely works one to line. Larger parts of code need to be considered and often changed coherently. As Cris says, it will be best to modify the remainder of the code? How exactly? Hard to say, you do not show it to us.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава Agree with what you said.